# React Native, button changing for all items in list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I created a flat list in which if user click buy button it should change but it's changing for every items. It should only change that item user buy. Can someone tell me what's wrong in my code, below is my code

FlatList

```
 <FlatList
              data={this.props.items}
              key={(items) => items.id.toString()}
              numColumns={2}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <CardBuyItem>
                  <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image} />
                  <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.subTitle} numberOfLines={1}>
                      {item.subTitle}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.price}>Rs {item.price}</Text>
                  </View>

                  {this.props.button && this.props.added.length > 0 ? (
                    <View style={styles.add}>
                      <Text style={styles.quantity}>{item.quantity}</Text>
                      <MaterialCommunityIcons
                        style={styles.iconUp}
                        size={20}
                        name="plus-circle-outline"
                        onPress={() => this.props.addQuantity(item.id)}
                      />
                      <MaterialCommunityIcons
                        style={styles.iconDown}
                        size={20}
                        name="minus-circle-outline"
                        onPress={() => this.props.subtractQuantity(item.id)}
                      />
                    </View>
                  ) : (
                    <View style={styles.buy}>
                      <Text
                        style={styles.buyonce}
                        onPress={() => {
                          this.props.addToCart(item.id);
                          this.props.showCart();
                          this.props.showButton(item.id);
                        }}
                      >
                        Buy Once
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  )}
                </CardBuyItem>
              )}
            />
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.clothes.jeans,
    button: state.clothes.showButton,
    added: state.clothes.addedItems,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addToCart: (id) => dispatch(addToCart(id)),
    addQuantity: (id) => dispatch(addQuantity(id)),
    subtractQuantity: (id) => dispatch(subtractQuantity(id)),
    showCart: () => dispatch(showCart()),
    showButton: (id) => dispatch(showButton(id)),
  };
};
```

that's my flat list where button should change for that particular item

reducer

```
 if (action.type === SHOW_BUTTON) {
    let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
    return {
      ...state,
      addedItem: addedItem,
      showButton: action.showButton,
    };
}

const initialstate = {  showButton: false}
```

that's my reducer

action

```
export const showButton = (id) => {
  return {
    type: SHOW_BUTTON,
    showButton: true,
    id,
  };
};
```

and that's my action for reducer

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `count` to your `item` and in your reducer put

```
 item.forEach(cp => {
      if (cp.id === action.id) {
        cp.count += 1;
      }
    });
```